# Delphi-7 Oracle-11g communication under heavy DB load using DOA

Tags: delphi, oracle11g, delphi-7

I have a problem that tough it might be found in other environments I would describe in the one I'm working on.
Delphi 7 App running over Windows 7 64
DOA 4.7 Direct Oracle Access Component
Oracle 11g

The application has a main window with a menu that opens a variety of forms. When opened, these forms usually retrieve some data from the Oracle DB. Under normal DB server load, the response is adequate.

The problem arises when there's a heavy load on the server and the response takes more time.

In this case the following happens:

- When the Form is launched, if it takes over a few seconds to retrieve the data, the form shows a "not responding" message on top, then the forms with the data goes behind the main form.
- After the retrieve operation is completed the form works as intended, but has that annoying behavior of “going behind”.

Any Ideas? I have the Delphi sources.

Comment: This is what you can expect when the DB code/components runs of the main thread, it will block th GUI when it is retrieving data. I don't know the DOA component, but maybe there is a way to operate in asynchronous mode...

Answer (score 0):

I finally arrived at a solution accepted by the customer. In HKEY_CURRENT_USER > Control Panel > Desktop
I added a registry entry type string (REG_SZ) named “HungAppTimeout” and value 50000
As the app runs in Citrix over Windows 2012 the new key was added to each user.
What this does is simply extend the time that windows takes before "ghosting" the app window and show a "not responding" caption. Now its 50 sec. compared to the 5 sec. default.